# How to insert multiple sections in collectionview at once?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

Actually i know how to insert one section at a time but i don't know 
how to insert multiple section at once?.

```
collectionView.insertSections(IndexSet(integer: array.count + 1))
```

how to insert multiple section at once?.

ex

```
var array = [3,4,2,1,6] // one section for one element

func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
   return array.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return array[section]
}

//now i want to add three new sections [8,5,9]
```

*[Api doc:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618090-insertsections)*

> Use this method to insert one or more sections into the collection
>   view. This method adds the sections,

Comment: @vadian now it make sence?

Comment: Please see the updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `IndexSet` can contain multiple indexes

```
collectionView.insertSections(IndexSet([2, 4, 7]))
```

**Edit:**

To insert 3 new sections at end of

```
var array = [3,4,2,1,6]
```

use

```
let startIndex = array.count
array.append(contentsOf: [8,5,9])
let endIndex = array.count
collectionView.insertSections(IndexSet(startIndex..<endIndex))
```

Comment: thanks, but suppose i have 5 sections and i want to add 3 new section at the end